# ActionBarSherlock tabs customization

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my application. I would like to use icons/images in the actionbar instead of the default tabs. But unfortunately the images/icons I used by using .setIcon(), I find that there is a lot of padding being applied before and after the image/icon on each tab, thus making it look ugly.

Current tabs image

[image]

Could any please guide as to what needs to be done for this?

Intended tabs image

[image]

Comment: You can edit the xml layout of actionbarsherlock and delete the padding ( or margin ) I think

Comment: @Miro Markarian: I tried that, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: there is no way it won't work. That is a 100% thing.. Maybe you're modifying the wrong layout

Comment: Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Letme build myself a test project and see what I can do

Comment: But anyway in the meanwhile you can headover to ActionBarSherlock's github and file a issue describing your problem. The actual developers see your message and respond fast..

Comment: I found this too. You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047417/android-actionbar-sherlock-remove-divider-between-tabs-altogether

Comment: @Miro Markarian: I tried with the above mentioned link, still no luck.
I even tried using a custom style having parent as 

'code'Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView.

Through this I could achieve adding images on the tab. But the problem I'm facing here is the same image gets added to the tabs whereas I need different images on different tabs.