# How to style Action Bar in styles.xml

Tags: android

I wanna remove the app icon from my action bar

I dont want the home icon there, I want to make more room for my other icons :) Now 4 of them are aligned to the right and the fifth one only shows up on the bottom when I press the settings key

I found this answer which looks promising

```
Open your styles.xml file and add below codes in your Actionbar style

<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Problem is, I dont know what do they refer to as "your Actionbar style"

**EDIT:**
after having read some answers here is what I did to my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"  >
```

and at the last line I get this error:

```
Attribute "theme" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "application".
```

and this is my styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme">
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Also I've tried

```
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

It only makes the home icon invisible but it is still taking the space. Why have they provided 5 non-working methods here, what is the point? Why does it have to be so frustrating.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html. check the docs

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170942/actionbarsherlock-tabs-customization) helps.

Comment: guys, I read those and I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue in the following way:
- removed my settings icon
- then made my Home icon look like a settings icon

Now I have to find a way to make the Home icon open up the navigation drawer
And I also have to find a way to remove the huge blank space on the right side of the Home button so my icons are evenly spread.